# How to check whether string contains specific string in c#

Tags: c#, string, list

I want to check whether the string contains another string.
For ex : I have 'program mangement' string in one list and 'computer program' string in another list. I want to return 'computer program' as a result. I have tried below things

```
List<string> strlist1 = new List<string>();
strlist1.Add("program mangement");
strlist1.Add("english language");

List<string> strlist2 = new List<string>();
strlist2.Add("computer program");
strlist2.Add("computer");
strlist2.Add("test");

foreach(var keys in strlist2)
{
  var result = strlist1.Where(x=>x.Contains(keys)).FirstOrDefault();     
  Console.WriteLine(result);     
 }
```

I want the result as 'Computer Program' as the program word contains in second list. But it is not returning any result. can anyone suggest how to return the desired result..

Comment: Could you clarify what the expected out is, and how this snippet's output differs from it?

Comment: Use String.Split  and String.Contains...

Comment: when you do strlist1.Where(x=>x.Contains(keys)).FirstOrDefault(); you are basically saying "does computer program contain computer program analytics" which is obviously false... when you do the other one strlist1.Where(x=>keys.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();  now you inverted the situation and now saying "does computer program analytics contain computer program" which is obviously true.

Comment: updated the question @Mureinik

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether `computer program analytics` contains `computer program`:

```
foreach (var keys in strlist2)
{
     var result = strlist1.Where(x => keys.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();
     Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If it is necessary  to check whether word, not the whole sentence, contains in another array, then we can split sentence in array of words and check them:

```
foreach (var keyList2 in strlist2)
{
    foreach (var keyList1 in strlist1)
    {
         var splittedWords_1= keyList1.Split(' ');
         var splittedWords_2 = keyList2.Split(' ');
         bool containsValues = splittedWords_1.Any(s1 => splittedWords_2.Contains(s1));                    
         if (containsValues)
         {
              Console.WriteLine(keyList2);
         }                   
    }                
}
```

Comment: @Kishore there is no such string `computer program` in `strlist1`

Comment: yes but program word is there i want to match that one and return the result

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help

```
var found = false;
foreach (var s in strlist1)
{
    found = strlist2.Any(c => c.Contains(s));
    if (found) break;
}
Console.WriteLine(found.ToString());
```